# JPA criteria API function convert or cast

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to convert the following SQL to CriteriaBuilder code

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM logging WHERE CONVERT(log_action, CHAR(100)) = 'delete'
```

log_action is defined as a varbinary(32).

CODE:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Logging> query = cb.createQuery(Logging.class);
Root<Logging> from = query.from(Logging.class);
Expression<Byte> path = from.get("logAction");
Expression<String> convertFunction = cb.function("CONVERT", String.class, path);

query.select(from);

Predicate predicate = cb.equal(convertFunction, "delete");

query.where(predicate);

return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: What kind of columns is log_action, please add DDL.

Comment: I'm getting the following error:java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.findFunctionReturnType(SessionFactoryHelper.java:399)
 org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.findFunctionReturnType(SessionFactoryHelper.java:391)
 org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode.dialectFunction(MethodNode.java:115)
 org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode.resolve(MethodNode.java:76)

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `logging` (
  `log_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `log_type` varbinary(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `log_action` varbinary(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying a lot with the function method of CriteriaQuery. I get stuck because

```
private static final String PG_TRANSLATE_TO = "char(100)";
    ParameterExpression<String> p = cb.parameter(String.class,"param0" );
Expression<String> convertFunction = cb.function("CONVERT", String.class, from.get("log_action"), p);
```

Always concatenate char(100), but using quotes 'char(100)', then SQL error comes.

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''char(100)')='delete'' at line 1

So I decide to make Criteria query directly to the bytes as they are String at the beginning.
And use the following code.

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery <Logging> query = cb.createQuery(Logging.class);

    ParameterExpression<String> p = cb.parameter(String.class,"param0" );
    Root<Logging> from = query.from(Logging.class);

    query.select(from);
        query.where( cb.equal(from.get("log_action"), "delete".getBytes()));

    System.out.println(em.createQuery(query).getResultList());
```

This really works

Hibernate: select logging0_.log_id as log1_3_, logging0_.log_action as log2_3_, logging0_.log_type as log3_3_ from Logging logging0_ where logging0_.log_action=?

[Logging [log_id=1, log_type=delete, log_action=null], Logging [log_id=2, log_type=delete, log_action=null], Logging [log_id=3, log_type=delete, log_action=null], Logging [log_id=4, log_type=delete, log_action=null], Logging [log_id=5, log_type=delete, log_action=null], Logging [log_id=6, log_type=delete, log_action=null], Logging [log_id=8, log_type=delete, log_action=null]]

To be honest probably with huge amount of data you will have a performance issue, but also I'm not sure about that XD. but at the end is a solution. Don't forget to give a like to my answer if it help you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run the CONVERT function correctly, use this code:

```
Expression<String> convertFunction = cb.function("CONVERT", String.class, log_action, cb.function("CHAR", Object.class, cb.literal(100)));
```

Comment: Is there a way to translate `CONVERT(col USING latin1)` or `CONVERT(col, CHAR(36) CHARACTER SET latin1)`? @rotem-wald @Koitoer